# How in golang to remove the last letter from the string?

Tags: go

Let's say I have a string called `varString`.

```
varString := "Bob,Mark,"
```

**QUESTION**: How to remove the last letter from the string? In my case, it's the second comma.

Comment: varString = varString[:len(varString)-1]

Comment: Terminology nitpick: `,` is not a letter :)

Comment: @georgeok: For `len(varString) == 0`, you will `panic`. For non-ASCII characters your result will be wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to remove the last letter from the string?

---

In Go, character strings are UTF-8 encoded. Unicode [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-length character encoding which uses one to four bytes per Unicode character (code point).

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func trimLastChar(s string) string {
    r, size := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(s)
    if r == utf8.RuneError && (size == 0 || size == 1) {
        size = 0
    }
    return s[:len(s)-size]
}

func main() {
    s := "Bob,Mark,"
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = trimLastChar(s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qyVYrjmBoVc

Output:

```
Bob,Mark,
Bob,Mark
```

Comment: `size == 0` seems to be redundant

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much simpler method that works for unicode strings too:

```
func removeLastRune(s string) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    return string(r[:len(r)-1])
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/ezsGUEz0F-D

Comment: Alert: This is a very inefficient. If wastes CPU time and memory by unnecessarily converting the entire string to a slice of rines and the slice of runes to a string.

Comment: @peterSO Admit, but that should matter if the input string is large enough. Most of the case this solution will do the job just fine.

Comment: Your answer is not "just fine". It is terrible. For the 9-character string in the question, it is 76.8 versus 4.51 ns/op, 17 times less efficient. For a 99-character string, it is 979 versus 4.50 ns/op, 217 times less efficient, and 528 B/op versus  0 B/op. Now, multiply that by Google scale.

Comment: @peterSO I definitely agree with the fact that your solution is more efficient than mine, but here I showed 'simpler' solution, not faster. And I think it is not true only the speed of a program matters, especially when judging others' solution terrible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
s := "Bob,Mark,"
s = s[:len(s)-1]
```

Note that this does not work if the last character is not represented by just one byte.

Comment: Alert: Go character strings are UTF-8 encoded. This answer only works for ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
newStr := strings.TrimRightFunc(str, func(r rune) bool {
    return !unicode.IsLetter(r) // or any other validation can go here
})
```

This will trim anything that isn't a letter on the right hand side.